# Differ between text above image, and text covered by image

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have tested the code provided [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66607663/how-to-use-pdfbox-to-extract-all-text-on-a-page-that-is-not-behind-an-image#). It can find all text elements which are included in an image bounding box. But how can you differ between text **behind** the image and text **above** the image ?

Comment: Have you checked [this older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20179928/1729265)? It provides a proof-of-concept for text extraction that ignores text covered by bitmap images.

Comment: Yes, I had to port it, replace `context.processSubStream` with `context.showForm`. Unfortunately It did not lead to the desired results. Maybe I did not mention the correct value for `OperatorProcessor.getName()`. What should be the value ? I understand you used `"Do"`, but it did not work for me.

Comment: Sorry, I have re-checked my code, did some cleanouts, and now it works !!!! Thank you @mkl !! Will paste the updated ported code in an answer below.

Comment: *"I had to port it"* - yes, considering the age of that answer, it may well have been a PDFBox 1.x answer. - *"now it works !!!!"* - Great!

Comment: @mkl The code is OK for PDF pages with `pdPage.getCropBox().getLowerLeftY() == 0` and `getLowerLeftX() == 0`. Any help with this [old thread comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19809813/how-to-check-if-a-text-is-transparent-with-pdfbox) would be much appriciated: `For a generic solution you have to change this test to something that checks whether the 1x1 square transformed by the Matrix ctm = getGraphicsState().getCurrentTransformationMatrix() overlaps the character box ... `

Answer (score 1):

Below pasted is the code of the [old answer mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20179928/1729265), ported to PDFBox 2.0.24. Main changes are:

- `getName()` method added
- `context.processSubStream` replaced with `context.showForm`
- `PDXObjectForm`, `PDXObjectImage` replaced with the new class names `PDFormXObject`, `PDImageXObject`.
- `drawer.getResources().getXObjects();` replaced with `drawer.getResources().getXObjectNames()` and iteration over the XObjects collection is based on the `getXObjectNames()` returned value.

```
public final class CoveredText extends OperatorProcessor
{
    @Override
    public void process(Operator operator, List<COSBase> operands) throws IOException{
        PDFVisibleTextStripper drawer = (PDFVisibleTextStripper)context;
        for (COSName objectName: drawer.getResources().getXObjectNames()) {
            PDXObject xobject = drawer.getResources().getXObject(objectName);
            if ( xobject == null )
            {
                System.out.println("CoveredText.process Can't find the XObject for '"+objectName.getName()+"'");
            }
            else if( xobject instanceof PDImageXObject )
            {
                System.out.println("CoveredText.process " + objectName.getName()+" is a PDImageXObject");
                drawer.hide(objectName.getName());
            }
            else if(xobject instanceof PDFormXObject)
            {                   
                PDFormXObject form = (PDFormXObject)xobject;
                System.out.println("CoveredText.process " + objectName.getName()+" is a PDFormXObject at localtion " + form.getBBox().toString());
                Matrix matrix = form.getMatrix();
                if (matrix != null) 
                {
                    Matrix xobjectCTM = matrix.multiply( context.getGraphicsState().getCurrentTransformationMatrix());
                    context.getGraphicsState().setCurrentTransformationMatrix(xobjectCTM);
                }
                context.showForm(form);                    
            }               
        }
    } 
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Do";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you change ? Where the issue come from and how you fix it ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This code is OK for PDF pages with `pdPage.getCropBox().getLowerLeftY() == 0` and `getLowerLeftX() == 0`. Any help with this old thread comment would be much appriciated: `For a generic solution you have to change this test to something that checks whether the 1x1 square transformed by the Matrix ctm = getGraphicsState().getCurrentTransformationMatrix() overlaps the character box ... `

Comment: location problem was solved by comparing the TextPosition to images bounding box, both in user space units.
I have another issue with the following page:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14qy_GPS3dzXI-meJiCKkvqwUb59Q1yWk/view?usp=sharing

I cannot get the string "ANNUAL REPORT 2018" which is printed behind th eimage on top right corner, to be detected as hidden (= covered), and the string "Destination2050" to be detected as visible = on top of image. Any help ?

Comment: I have removed the PDF sample from my cloud folder. It is available here: https://s25.q4cdn.com/680186029/files/doc_financials/ar-interactive/2018-interactive/ar/images/Xcel_Energy-AR2018.pdf 
The problem is on page 14 (zero based counting)